# Python: list manipulation using del or list.remove

Tags: python, list, del

I am trying to write a function. This function takes a list of numbers as input, finds the largest sequence of consecutive numbers in this list and returns a list containing only this largest sequence of numbers of the original list.

Example:

```
In [2]: largestSeq([1,2,3,4,1,2,3])
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It works as long as the input list has 0 or more than 1 elements in it.
I included print statements in my code to see where the error is.

Here is the code and the result of calling `largestSeq([1])`and `largestSeq([1,2])`:

### Code:

```
def findSeq(seq):                    #this finds a sequence of consecutive numbers 
        i = 0                        #in a list and returns it
        if len(seq) <= 1:            #it stops when the next number in the list 
            return seq                #is smaller than the former
        s =[seq[0]]
        while seq[i] < seq[i+1]:
            i += 1
            s.append(seq[i])
            if i == len(seq)-1:
                break
        return s
def largestSeq(seq,a=[]):
    b = findSeq(seq)                 #find the first consecutive sequence
    if len(seq) == 0:
        return a
    print 'Length of b is ' + str(len(b))
    if len(b) > len(a):            #check if found sequence is bigger than 
        print 'seq is now ' + str(seq)#the last found sequence
        print 'b is now ' + str(b)
        i = len(b)
        print 'now deleting elements of seq'
        for d in range (i):
            seq.remove(seq[0])    #remove found sequence from the original 
        #del seq[0:i]            #list
        print 'seq is now ' + str(seq)
        print 'b is now ' + str(b)
        return largestSeq(seq,b) #start over
    else:
        del seq[0:len(b)]
        return largestSeq(seq,a)
```

### And now the calls:

```
In [14]: largestSeq([1])
Length of b is 1
seq is now [1]
b is now [1]
now deleting elements of seq
seq is now []
b is now []
Out[14]: []
largestSeq([1,2])
Length of b is 2
seq is now [1, 2]
b is now [1, 2]
now deleting elements of seq
seq is now []
b is now [1, 2]
Out[15]: [1, 2]
```

Please note, that in the first call, the element in `b` is also deleted after deleting element of `seq` , althoug I didn't change it!
In the second call with `[1,2]` `b` is behaving like I want it, while `seq` is deleted.

I tried manipulating the list with `list.remove` and with `del` (which is commented out and yields the same error).

What is going on in there? I don't understand it.
I want `b` remaining unchanged in the first call, like it does in the second call.

This is a very specific question. I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: One note unrelated: When you are searching for the longest sequence if you stop when the next number is smaller than the current number then you may return lists like [1, 2, 4, 67, 89]. I am not sure if this is what you want but if it isn't you should check to see if the next number == current number + 1.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Maybe I didn't articulate the problem well enough. A list like yours would also be okay for the function.

Comment: No problem. I just wanted to make sure that wasn't causing you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are returning the same list, you have to return a copy of the list.

Try:

```
def findSeq(seq):                    #this finds a sequence of consecutive numbers 
        i = 0                        #in a list and returns it
        if len(seq) <= 1:            #it stops when the next number in the list 
            return list(seq)                #is smaller than the former
        s =[seq[0]]
        while seq[i] < seq[i+1]:
            i += 1
            s.append(seq[i])
            if i == len(seq)-1:
                break
        return s
```

Comment: That works perfectly!
I didn't expect an answer to appear so fast, cool!
But I don't understand why it works, could you elaborate on this?
Why is return list(seq) different to return seq?

Comment: You can read an explanation, here: http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list I think is a good explanation.

Comment: I see the explanation and it helped a little. But how comes that the whole thing just doesn't work with lists that contain only 1 element?
It's fine with everything else.

Comment: Because in the first case you are returning the list, but in the second case you are returning a new list generated adding element by element.